# Error Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined when running test file in react component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I created test for a component.This component will show the detail page of data. everything is running well, but I got this error when I run the test suite file
[image]

structure directory:
[image]

and this is my test code
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is happening because inside your source code there is queryData variable which you need to mock while testing.So let's say if queryData is being returned by some function,then in your test file mock that function and the mocked function should return data having a property as `getCommunity`